# System info - bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, system-settings

I am attempting to pull RX packets, CPU vendor and model along with CPU MHz.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#systemstat

case $1="-r"
COUNT='ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX packets:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}''
DATE='date +"%H:%M:%S"' echo "Time" $'\t' $'\t' "Total Packets eth0" echo $DATE $'\t' $'\t'$COUNT ;; "-c"
VENDOR='cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'vendor_id' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}''
MODEL='cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep 'model name' | cut -d: -f2' CPU='more /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu MHz' | cut -d:$

*) echo

;; esac
```

I am getting the following error:

```
./systemstat: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `COUNT='ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX'
./systemstat: line 6: `COUNT='ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX packets:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'' '
```

Can anyone assist?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sincerely, your script is a mess. Before to start with bash scripting, you should read first something like: [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html).

Now, your script should look like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#systemstat

case $1 in
"-r")
    COUNT=`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX packets:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`
    DATE=`date +"%H:%M:%S"`
    echo -e "Time\t\tTotal Packets eth0" 
    echo -e "$DATE\t\t$COUNT"
    ;; 
"-c")
    VENDOR=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'vendor_id' | cut -d: -f2 | awk 'NR==1'`
    MODEL=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -d: -f2 | awk 'NR==1'` 
    MHZ=`more /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu MHz' | cut -d: -f2 | awk 'NR==1'`
    echo -e "CPU Model:\n $MODEL" 
    echo -e "Vendor:\n $VENDOR" 
    echo -e "MHZ:\n $MHZ" 
    ;;

*) 
    echo -e "Usage: `basename $0` OPTION\n\tOPTIONS:\n\t\t-r -> some explanation\n\t\t-c -> some explanation"
    ;; 
esac
```

See also: [Using case statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html).